# I can't seem to get my Javascript form validation to work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

This is my first time trying form validation, and I can't seem to get it to work. I looked at the w3schools code on how to do it, and mine looks quite similar, it just won't work though:

Here is my function:

```
function validateUserName(NewUser) {
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]
    var length = u.length;
    if (u.user.value = null || u.user.value = "") {
        alert("You left Username field empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is my form:

```
<form name="NewUser" onsubmit="return validateUserName()" action="">
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Information"><em>4-11 characters...</em></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Please ignore the table code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using assignment operator. In the `if` condition your are using `=` for comparision, it is the assignment operator you need to use `==` for comparison operator

```
function validateUserName() {
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]
    var length = u.length;
    if (u.user.value == null || u.user.value == "") {
        alert("You left Username field empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZTSev/1/)