# jQuery if statement syntax check

Tags: jquery

Whats wrong with this statement.

```
if (data.bookingtype = 'Corporate') {
    jQuery('#rentalprice').val(data.baserentalprice);

} else if (data.bookingtype = 'Groups') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);

} else if (data.bookingtype = 'Leisure') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);

}
```

I am trying to populate a field based on the value of the bookingtype variable sent back from my ajax request.

If bookingtype is Corporate then populate the #rentalprice input, else if its Groups or Leisure then populate the #priceperperson input. At the moment it always populate the #rentalprice input.

Comment: `==` or `===` (equality operator) instead of `=` (assignment operator)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250235/i-cant-seem-to-get-my-javascript-form-validation-to-work and what not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning value to the variable instead of comparing. So, the first `if` is always evaluated to `true` and the statement of `if` block will be executed.

Use [`equality operator(==)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) or [`strict equality operator(===)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) instead of [`assignment operator(=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

```
if (data.bookingtype == 'Corporate') {
    jQuery('#rentalprice').val(data.baserentalprice);
} else if (data.bookingtype == 'Groups') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);
} else if (data.bookingtype == 'Leisure') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);
}
```

Comment: Why Downvote? Please add comments here. Can something be improved?

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment operator `=` instead of equality operator `==` or `===`.
The code should be as follows:

**JQUERY**

```
if (data.bookingtype == 'Corporate') {
    jQuery('#rentalprice').val(data.baserentalprice);
} else if (data.bookingtype == 'Groups') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);
} else if (data.bookingtype == 'Leisure') {
    jQuery('#priceperperson').val(data.baserentalprice);
}
```